# dplyr- cumulative sum of a column, based on comparisons with other columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm reading in some XY data from a file, and need to do a cumulative sum on the Y ordinate with steps coarser than that in the original data.

How can I do a cumsum on a the Y column based on X values in other columns?

```
library(tidyverse)
x_data <- seq(2, 5, 0.2) # this is read in from a file
y_data <- runif(length(x_data)) # this is read in from a file
input_data <- tibble(x_data, y_data)

x_steps <- seq(2, 5, 1)
final_data = tibble(x_steps)

#how to cumsum input_data$y_data based on final_data$x_steps?
#x_data and x_steps are guarenteed to be strictly increasing
```

*edit:
Some example data:

```
# input_data
2.0   0.55005588
2.2   0.27577714
2.4   0.24215415
2.6   0.70794255
2.8   0.30632029
3.0   0.71693474
3.2   0.49712663
3.4   0.21227011
3.6   0.74823731
3.8   0.90176957
4.0   0.52331898
4.2   0.79409880
4.4   0.04228391
4.6   0.06220941
4.8   0.50969235
5.0   0.11734668
```

should turn into:

```
#final_data
2.0   0.55005588
3.0   2.79918475
4.0   5.68190735
5.0   7.2075385
```

Comment: Could you please show the head of the expected output?

Comment: @TarJae example data added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative solution:

```
input_data %>%
  mutate(id = as.integer(cut(x_data, breaks = 0:max(x_data)))) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(sum = sum(y_data)) %>%
  mutate(cumsum_ydata = cumsum(sum))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can try

```
library(tidyverse)

input_data |>
           mutate(x_steps = rev(trunc(x_data))) |>
           group_by(x_steps) |> 
           summarise(cum_y_data = sum(y_data)) |>
           mutate(cum_y_data = rev(cum_y_data)) |> 
           mutate(cum_y_data = cumsum(cum_y_data))
```

- output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  x_steps cum_y_data
    <dbl>      <dbl>
1       2      0.550
2       3      2.80 
3       4      5.68 
4       5      7.21
```

Answer (score 1):

Though not the most elegant solution, if you wanted/neded a brute-force base R approach:

```
want <- matrix(NA, ncol = 2, nrow = length(x_steps))
for(xx in seq_along(x_steps)){
  res <- seq(x_steps[xx], x_steps[xx] + 1, 0.0001)
  want[xx,] <- c(x_steps[xx], 
                 max(cumsum(input_data[input_data$x_data %in% res[-length(res)], "y_data"])))
}
```

Output:

```
#>want
#[,1]     [,2]
#[1,]    2 3.308344
#[2,]    3 1.581712
#[3,]    4 2.660372
#[4,]    5 0.899825
```

If the steps are truly lower resolution, an easier `dplyr()` approach may be to use `floor()` then perform some basic functions:

```
input_data %>% 
  group_by(floor(x_data)) %>% 
  mutate(cum_sum = cumsum(y_data)) %>%
  filter(row_number() == n()) %>%
  select(cum_sum)
```

Output:

```
  `floor(x_data)` cum_sum
            <dbl>   <dbl>
1               2   3.31 
2               3   2.47 
3               4   2.76 
4               5   0.900
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `tidyverse` approach: Last 2 lines same as @deschen:

Main challenge is to group for summing. Here we use a combination of `coalesce`, `str_extract` and `parse_number` to group:

```
library(tidyverse)

input_data %>% 
  group_by(id = coalesce(parse_number(str_extract(x_data, '\\d+\\.'))+1, x_data)) %>% 
  summarise(sum = sum(y_data)) %>% 
  mutate(cumsum_ydata = cumsum(sum))
```

```
      id    sum cumsum_ydata
   <dbl>  <dbl>        <dbl>
 1     2  0.874        0.874
 2     3 49.2         50.1  
 3     4 48.7         98.8  
 4     5 45.0        144.   
 5     6 48.2        192.   
 6     7 49.1        241.   
 7     8 47.4        289.   
 8     9 46.1        335.   
 9    10 50.8        385.   
10    11 51.1        437.   
# ... with 154 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

```
x_steps <- seq(2, 5, 1)
final_data <-  tibble(x_steps)
final_data <- final_data  %>% mutate(id=cut(x_steps, breaks=c(-Inf, x_steps), labels=seq(2, 5, 1)))

x_data <- seq(2, 5, 0.2) # this is really read in from a file
y_data <- runif(length(x_data)) # this is really read in from a file
input_data <- tibble(x_data, y_data)

final_data <- input_data %>% 
  mutate(id=cut(x_data, breaks=c(-Inf, x_steps), labels=seq(2, 5, 1))) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(totals=sum(y_data)) %>% 
  mutate(csum = cumsum(totals)) %>% 
  select(c("id", "csum")) %>% 
  right_join(final_data, by="id") %>% 
  relocate(x_steps)
```

I stuck with the explicit ID column, as I wanted to join it back to the `final_data` tibble, along with other calculations.

Part my own deductions, part taking from @deschen